# Office features disabled in standalone Outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2007

I have Office 2007 basic suite installed on my computer. I installed Outlook 2010 from a volume license provided by our Email Server Provider. When creating a new email all of the Office features are disabled in the ribbon. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509316) microsoft support article describes my issue, however I do not have Office installed as click and run.

It seems to me that there should be a way to make outlook recognize the office suite already installed.

The "add or remove features" dialogue accessed through programs and features from the control panel seems promising, however its only options for "office features" are run from computer, or install on 1st run.

I can't seem to find any valid articles online that aren't just dealing with the click to run issue.

I know that there are several people at my company with the same set up, installed the same way that have everything working fine.

How can I get my standalone Outlook 2010 install to recognize the Office 2007 basic suite?

Comment: This is interesting. *Can* Outlook 2010 use Office 2007 features at all? I've never tried.

Comment: I know for a fact that it works on several other of our computers at my workplace. The features I'm talking about are just autocorrect, spell check, insert tables/graphs. I guess my question sounds silly hence the downvote? It is a legitimate issue though.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get my standalone Outlook 2010 install to recognize the
>   Office 2007 basic suite?

You cannot.

Outlook 2010 is included in Office 2010.  Outlook 2010 isn't not contained within Office 2007